# How to check the keys only of passing object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to pass `obj` to `selectMap` with typescript support.

And I want to make sure the keys pass to the function. I don't want to check the value type.

How I can achieve this with typescript? I have try to do `keyof` but typescript throw error.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-voice-q2vqc?file=/src/index.ts)

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  age: number;
}

function selectMap<T>(obj: keyof T) {}

selectMap<User>({
  id: 'id',
  firstName: 'first_name',
  age: 'age'
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to mean "an object whose keys are of type `K` and whose values are of type `V`".  You want `obj` to be a value of a type like `Record<keyof T, any>` instead of just `keyof T`:

```
function selectMap<T>(obj: Record<keyof T, any>) { }

selectMap<User>({
    id: 'id',
    firstName: 'first_name',
    age: 'age'
}); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcBxyMwU6YAcnLRErcooAOYtCxOKMFU6jKBIC+BAjGogEYYAHsQyTABsIWgLJwADgB4AKgD4AFDvoArSgCUTOqKSsBrCABPHRhkGwAaZDgQQLsAShxkFXwCIxMwc2sMaEc8SSIySgByMiLw1mIOLl5+WSKq7gB9EFqyiqJpOs6igiU41XwgA)